# How to change Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop file manager (not gnome)?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop

Is there anyway to use a different desktop than the one that ships with this Ubuntu?

I'm sorry if the question is weak, I understand I can change display managers and so on, but the new desktop is so detached from any file explorer (I use nautilus), it is off putting.

Comment: If talking about changing The Desktop, you just need to install a desktop you like.  Have to know that some desktops work well together on same system, others do not.  Would prefer someone to try different desktops on a VM system before doing it on their main system.

Comment: Thank you @crip659, someone also marked my question as a duplicate, I understand that I can change from gnome to kde (for example) but I don't want that, I just want to change the file manager attached to my desktop screen, I'm finding trouble explaining it or maybe it's not possible as they are considered 1

Comment: It is basically the same way.  Choose a file manager you want and install.  I know there a few, most desktops have their own, but quite sure they can be installed separately.  Would still try out in a VM to make sure they work well.  Default Ubuntu uses nautilus file manager for gnome and unity desktops.  Try googling ubuntu/linux file managers to get an idea what is available.

Comment: Just googled it myself, there are dozens, one should be to your liking, but don't ask for opinions.  Just confuses us, get more opinions than file managers.

Comment: I already use nautilus, but the desktop was detached from the file explorer you use in 20.04. If I understand it correctly, I think they implemented minimum file explorer functionality (it's buggy and doesn't work well with others) and that is the part I want to change, not install a file explorer, but have the desktop "utilize" nautilus (like it used too in previous versions)

Comment: Think it might be better to make new question, explaining why you find naulitus buggy now and how to fix.  Add in Ubuntu version and I guess you are using Gnome desktop.

Comment: I think my issue now is trying to explain the issue xD I don't have a problem with my file explorer I have a problem with the file explorer features of ubuntu 20.04 desktop only (the icons on your desktop above the wallpaper) that's it

Comment: Can you see this link and see if it is close to your problem, maybe help explain your problem better.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095891/nautilus-menu-bar-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly, but you can change the background image by right-clicking on it and selecting "Change background".
Or searching for "Background" in settings.

Comment: I mean the file explorer features for a desktop (eg. file: copy, paste, sort icons.. etc)